# Rotating a vector with radians

Tags: c++, glm-math, vectormath

I'm trying to have the camera always move up with its rotation so if you press w it will always move you up at the same speed as pressing s but in the oposite direction. The problem now is that the velocity added to the camera is unreliable and not what i'm trying to get.

```
void OrthographicCameraController::CameraAddRelativeVelocity(Timestep ts, glm::vec2 velocity)
    {

        glm::vec2 rotatedVelocity(
            velocity.x * cos(glm::radians(m_CameraRotation)) + velocity.y * 
sin(glm::radians(m_CameraRotation)),
            velocity.x * sin(glm::radians(m_CameraRotation)) + velocity.y * cos(glm::radians(m_CameraRotation))
        );

        m_CameraVelocity += rotatedVelocity * (ts.GetMilliseconds() * 0.1f);

        //LOG_INFO("x, {0} y: {1}", velocity.x, velocity.y);
```

The camera should always go up relative to itself but at the same speed in all directions. For some reason this code gives a seamingly random pattern of velocity to the camera even tho the math checks out. The input to this function is the function below that basicly checks for inputs and first increase velocity with an acceleration speed and then decrease with a retardation speed. Ive checked the numbers and the code below works. It's  the CameraAddVecolity function that's disfunctional.

```
    bool xNegative = 0 > m_CameraVelocity.x;
    bool xPositive = 0 < m_CameraVelocity.x;
    
    bool yNegative = 0 > m_CameraVelocity.y;
    bool yPositive = 0 < m_CameraVelocity.y;

    glm::vec2 velToAdd = {0.0f, 0.0f};
    


    if ((Input::IsKeyPressed(HZ_KEY_D) - Input::IsKeyPressed(HZ_KEY_A)) == 0) {
        
        if (m_CameraMovementRetardation * m_MaxCameraTranslationSpeed * ts > m_CameraVelocity.x && m_CameraMovementRetardation * m_MaxCameraTranslationSpeed * ts > -m_CameraVelocity.x) {
            m_CameraVelocity.x = 0;
        }
        else {
            m_CameraVelocity.x += m_CameraMovementRetardation * (xNegative - xPositive) * m_MaxCameraTranslationSpeed * ts;
        }

    } else {
        velToAdd.x = (Input::IsKeyPressed(HZ_KEY_D) - Input::IsKeyPressed(HZ_KEY_A)) * m_CameraMovementAcceleration * m_MaxCameraTranslationSpeed * ts;
    }


    if ((Input::IsKeyPressed(HZ_KEY_W) - Input::IsKeyPressed(HZ_KEY_S)) == 0) {

        if (m_CameraMovementRetardation * m_MaxCameraTranslationSpeed * ts > m_CameraVelocity.y && m_CameraMovementRetardation * m_MaxCameraTranslationSpeed * ts > -m_CameraVelocity.y) {
            m_CameraVelocity.y = 0;
        }
        else {
            m_CameraVelocity.y += m_CameraMovementRetardation * (yNegative - yPositive) * m_MaxCameraTranslationSpeed * ts;
        }

    }
    else {
        velToAdd.y = (Input::IsKeyPressed(HZ_KEY_W) - Input::IsKeyPressed(HZ_KEY_S)) * m_CameraMovementAcceleration * m_MaxCameraTranslationSpeed * ts;
    }


    // Camera rotation
    
    if (m_Rotation)
    {
        if (Input::IsKeyPressed(HZ_KEY_E))
            m_CameraRotation += m_MaxCameraRotationSpeed * ts;
        if (Input::IsKeyPressed(HZ_KEY_Q))
            m_CameraRotation -= m_MaxCameraRotationSpeed * ts;

        if (m_CameraRotation > 180.0f)
            m_CameraRotation -= 360.0f;
        else if (m_CameraRotation <= -180.0f)
            m_CameraRotation += 360.0f;

        m_Camera.SetRotation(m_CameraRotation);
    }

    m_WorldSpaceMovement ? CameraAddWorldSpaceVelocity(ts, velToAdd) : CameraAddRelativeVelocity(ts, velToAdd);

    m_CameraVelocity = glm::clamp(m_CameraVelocity, -m_MaxCameraTranslationSpeed, m_MaxCameraTranslationSpeed);

    m_CameraPosition += m_CameraVelocity;
    m_Camera.SetPosition(m_CameraPosition);

    m_MaxCameraTranslationSpeed = m_ZoomLevel;
```

Comment: Where is timestep ts coming from and why do you sometimes call  GetMilliseconds and sometimes not?

Comment: It returns m_Time * 1000. Its a bad way of multiplying by 1000

Comment: Your expression for rotated velocity is wrong. Depending on whether it is a passive or active rotation one of those sines needs a minus sign. You can see it isn’t a rotation because the determinant of the matrix wouldn’t be 1.0

Comment: bro i'm 15 explain in sweat and what is the meaning of life terms

Comment: Your expression glm::vec2 rotatedVelocity(… has two terms involving cos(…) and two terms involving sin(…). One of the two sin() terms should be preceded by a minus (-) sign, not a plus(+). If you don’t understand it then you probably copied it from somewhere. Go back and find where you miscopied.

Comment: It still is giving wierd results. The camera is still moving in unexpected ways.